# Using visual driver to identify on screen keyboard button with instrumentation value True in Perfecto Selenium Automation

Tags: ios, selenium-webdriver, keyboard, automation

My test app is installed with instrumentation value True on Perfecto cloud. I understand that with instrumentation value True the on screen keyboard elements cannot be identified. We have to use visual driver to resolve this.

*Question:- How to identify elements on keyboard which doesn't has any text associated with it. Example - the Delete button on the keyboard. 
My test case needs the Delete button execution*

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to simulate delete button action? If so, have you tried using `sendKeys()` with [Keys](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html)?

It allows you to simulate any keyboard events.

*Sample java code*

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement("locator");
element.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
```

Comment: What is locator in this? Is this the xpath? The issue which I am facing is I want to click the Delete button, which doesn't have a xpath associated to it hence I am looking for a different way.
I tried the way you mentioned but the locator is the xpath which I dont have for the Delete keys

Comment: locator is whatever locator you want to use. Provide the `html` of the element in order to see if it is possible to write a selector for that element

Comment: Thats where I am stuck. The test framework is on perfecto cloud so the devices are like simulators on screen and I cant get any HTML for this.

Comment: Ok got you. I am not even sure how you want to test UI where UI is not available. Doesn't that defeat the purpose?

Comment: In perefecto cloud the elements object are available which can be used in xpath but in some case like the keyboard it doesn't has. So I researched and I got that visual driver can be used to identify such objects.